# Updating, and opening filenames in a loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Basically, the problem I'm have is trying to open multiple files in a for loop. The filename has this format:

```
filename = 'mms1_fgm_srvy_l2_20160104_v4.18.0.cdf'
```

With '20160104' being the date, which I know how to update in the loop. The problem is that the '18' attached at the end isn't constant for every file, and I don't know how it changes, unlike the dates. I was wondering is there is a way to update the number, and check if the file exists in my directory.

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you try use glob to list directory and os.path.isfile to verify file exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) function with a suitable filename pattern to get a list of files (that exist) which match the pattern.

For example:

```
import glob

pattern = 'mms1_fgm_srvy_l2_*_v4.*.0.cdf'

for filename in glob.glob(pattern):
    with open(filename) as file:
        process(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
BASE_NAME = 'mms1_fgm_srvy_l2_20160104_v4.{}.0'
EXT = '.cdf'

attempts = int(input('Check file up to: '))


for num in range(attempts):
    file_name = BASE_NAME.format(num) + EXT
    if os.path.isfile(file_name):
        # open file here
        print("Opened File")
    else:
        print("File does not exist")
```

Checks if the file exists and if it does you can load it and save it how ever you want else it will print the the file doesn't exist